# Orienting iOS splash image to landscape/portrait according to launch orientation

Tags: ios, landscape, splash-screen, portrait

I have an app that can launch in portrait or landscape. I'd like the Default.png file (the splash image that appears when the app launches) to show the image in the correct orientation so I expect I'd need to use two different images (different dimensions). I don't know how to make the app pick which image to use based on its launching orientation, however. Is this possible? Is there any way to know what orientation the app is launching in (before the splash is shown) and then pick the correct image, or do I simply have to settle with either having the image rotated sideways in one of the orientations or having an image that is indistinguishable at 90 degree rotations?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can name your start up images specifically for the orientation and each one will be displayed for that orientation

1. `Default-Portrait.png`
2. `Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png`
3. `Default-Landscape.png`
4. `Default-LandscapeLeft.png`
5. `Default-LandscapeRight.png`

Comment: Important to note - for the upside down images, they are actually created right-side up, not upside down as you might think.

Comment: Note that the above only applies to iPad at this point. iPhone/iPod touch only cares about Default.png

Answer (score 12):

See: http://iosdevelopertips.com/ipad/ipad-managing-multiple-launch-images.html

> When loading an application on an
>   iPhone or iPad, a launch image can be
>   shown to provide feedback to the user
>   that the application is loading. On
>   the iPhone one Default.png file was
>   adequate, with the iPad one needs to
>   anticipate the device being started in
>   any orientation, including upside
>   down.
>
> ### iPad Launch Image Orientations
>
> To deal with various orientation
>   options, a new naming convention has
>   been created for iPad launch images.
>   The screen size of the iPad is
>   768×1024, notice in the dimensions
>   that follow the height takes into
>   account a 20 pixel status bar.
>
> Filename, Dimensions
>
> `Default-Portrait.png * (768w x 1004h)`
>
> `Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png   (768w x 1004h)`
>
> `Default-Landscape.png ** (1024w x 748h)`
>
> `Default-LandscapeLeft.png    (1024w x 748h)`
>
> `Default-LandscapeRight.png   (1024w x 748h)`
>
> `Default.png  (Not recommended)`
>
> - If you have not specified a Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png file,
>     this file will take precedence.
> - If you have not specified a Default-LandscapeLeft.png or
>     Default-LandscapeRight.png image file,
>     this file will take precedence.
>     Although you can include a Default.png
>     file, and it will be used if no others
>     are specified, I would consider it a
>     best-practice to include all the
>     relevant images needed by your
>     application.

See also apple.com: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1588/_index.html, "Provide Launch Images".

Note:

> **iPhone-only applications:**
>
> iPhone-only applications may only have
>   one launch image.

And: [(Apple) Providing Launch Images for Different Orientations](https://web.archive.org/web/20111007071119/http://developer.apple.com:80/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW11), [(Apple) Launch Image Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/LaunchImageType.html)

**EDIT 28/06/2014**: This answer is from 2011 and as pointed out by @AlexShaffer: "These resolutions listed above are out of date for iOS 7. Launch images for iOS 7 include the status bar area. You should probably also use image catalogs for iOS 7 instead of using images with a naming convention: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html"

Comment: These resolutions listed above are out of date for iOS 7. Launch images for iOS 7 include the status bar area. You should probably also use image catalogs for iOS 7 instead of using images with a naming convention: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html

Comment: @AlexShaffer definitely! This answer is from 2011 and quite a few things have changed. I recommend that you edit the answer so that it's up to date.