# What filename do I save iphone icons as?

Tags: iphone, icons, itunes, itunesartwork

In the [Apple Human Interface guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) it has a list of all the required and optional icons/images one needs to supply.

However, I am not sure what filename to save the icons as for iTunes readiness.

For example, I believe:

- Application icon (57x57) -> *icon.png*
- App Store icon (512x512) -> Not
  sure??  Should it be itunes.png?
- Small icon for Spotlight (29 x 29) ->
  Not sure?? Should it be
  spotlight.png?
- Document icon (22 x 29) -> Not sure??
  Should it be document.png?
- Web clip icon (57 x 57) -> Again, not
  sure. Should it be web.png?
- Launch image (320 x 480) -> 
  *default.png*

What should these images/icons be saved as?

In the the case of the App Store icon (as used in iTunes), do I bundle/include this in my final bundle or is it kept separate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html) out regarding the icons.

As for launch images, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781846/orienting-ios-splash-image-to-landscape-portrait-according-to-launch-orientation).

Regarding the "App Store icon", no, you don't need to include it in the project's resources. And anyway, it should be named iTunesArtwork .