# How to Launch Splash Screen in LandScape mode in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, splash-screen

I am developing an application which is in Landscape mode Only.

In my application I am using a splash Screen Image (480 X 320). When I am running Xcode the Splash image appears in Portrait mode only but the view is in Landscape mode only.

Can Anyone suggest how to implement this splash Screen in Landscape mode?

Comment: This question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781846/orienting-ios-splash-image-to-landscape-portrait-according-to-launch-orientation

Answer (score 2):

Launch in landscape mode and make your **Default.png** be landscape.

**From the docs:**

**How do I start my application in landscape mode?**

> To start your application in landscape
>   mode, edit your Info.plist file to add
>   the UIInterfaceOrientation key with
>   the appropriate value
>   (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
>   or
>   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft),
>   as shown in Listing 1. This provides a
>   hint to the system to set the
>   orientation of the status bar
>   appropriately at launch time.

Listing 1: Starting your application in landscape mode

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
```

Check [this](http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesdkdevelopment/browse_thread/thread/ef734379136f09e9) for more.