# Can iOS launcher image and Cordova Splashscreen use different pictures?

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen

I am working on a iOS project with Cordova. The Project is in Landscape only.

If I copy a Default.png in the Project folder, it is displayed correctly in the launcher image but in the Cordova splash screen it is rotated by 90°.

If I rotate the Default.png the launcher image is oddly stretched and the Cordova splash screen is is shown perfectly.

The Landscape/Portrait tag doesn't work because Cordova just uses the Landscape-image.

Is there a way to use different images for the launcher and the splash screen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set all the splahs screens in the Resources folder. Then in iOS you can also set what orientations you want your application work in. If you be specific with your splash screens then it can only show what you put in there.

Short answer - I beileve the launch image an splash screen are one  in teh same.

This question looks similar - [Orienting iOS splash image to landscape/portrait according to launch orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781846/orienting-ios-splash-image-to-landscape-portrait-according-to-launch-orientation?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you. I created .png's for all orientations but it doesn't help.
The Splashscreen still appears rotated by 90° and only covering half of the screen. 
If the exact same Image is used, shouldn't it be displayed in the same way?