# Splash screen is landscape although the whole game is in the portrait mode. SpriteBuilder + cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, info.plist, spritebuilder

When I run SpriteBuilder cocos2d project in Xcode Simulator, splash screen is landscape and the whole game after it is in the portrait mode, as I set it in SpriteBuilder project settings. Mode is set portrait in the .plist file, and after I replaced default portrait image with my own and deleted  default landscape images, it just shows my portrait splash image in the landscape mode. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .plist, I checked, was actually a .plist file generated by cocos2d framework or SpriteBuilder. I also must change `Supported interface orientations`in the native Xcode .plist file - I just didn't see it and thought, that another one .plist file is the only one, that can be.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your image files are named according to the [answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781846/orienting-ios-splash-image-to-landscape-portrait-according-to-launch-orientation).

Try cleaning your project and deleting the app from the simulator/device. I have found Xcode sometimes likes to cache files in the simulator/device.

Comment: I'v done everything you say. Now happens just the same, but after a landscape image comes a portrait one(just for a second). Also, colors are very different. Do you know, how to fix it?